# Call an URL on debian from command shell

Tags: shell, command, http

I need a command which will just send http request to required web directory? Does something like this exist?

Comment: `curl` and `wget`, for example.

Comment: What is a “web **directory**”? Give an example, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of ways:

`nc www.example.com 80`: upside is you have full controll over what you send, downside is you are on your own. Restrict to HTTP 1.0 to minimize the things you need to type `GET / HTTP/1.0` followed by an empty line is all you need.

`curl http://www.example.com/`: good for normal use and debugging. Has lots of options. Especially usefull: `--verbose` to see the HTTP request/response and `--head` to send a HEAD request (no body).

`openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443`: Useful for debugging HTTPS servers.

`wget`: good for download and maybe more.

`w3m`, `lynx`, `links`: text-only browser.

Comment: Downvote because of Telnet. Telnet has numerous shortcomings as a TCP client.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: fixed.

Comment: Also consider `GET`, `POST` and `HEAD` (symlinks to `lwp-request`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` to send an http request. For example:

```
wget http://unix.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use curl

```
curl http://www.example.com/
```

with a variable:

```
page_content=`curl http://www.example.com`
echo $page_content
```

(posting this separately to make SO voting possible).